# When writing the integral sign $\int$, how does one know what integral is being discussed?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

We have the Lebesgue integral and the Riemann Integral. Generally, must the integral sign $\int$ refer to one or the other exclusively or does it depend on the integrand? Can someone provide intuition to this concept?

For example, in college-level Calculus courses, what integral is actually being used here?

Comment: Some people use $\int_{L}$ and $\int_{R}$ to represent these integrals, but I'm not a fan of that convention at all... I have also seen $\int_{D}$ to represent the Darboux integral. I would imagine that the integral sign has to be defined in context, or it would be ambiguous. :/

Comment: It really depends on the context.

Comment: @Cameron. For example, what about in college-level Calculus?

Comment: @Clarinetist Except in formulating the foundations, there is no distinction between the Riemann and Darboux integrals. We only distinguish between them temporarily in order to prove that they are equivalent. Except when talking about this equivalence, both are just called Riemann integrals.

Comment: In introductory calculus, the Riemann integral is most definitely what is meant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If a function is continuous on some closed interval then the two integrals will agree, hence a distinction is not necessary. Otherwise I believe the context should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

There are only two situations where it could be unclear:

1. The integral is on a compact interval, $f$ is not Riemann integrable and is Lebesgue integrable;
2. The integral is not on a compact interval, $f$ is improperly Riemann integrable and not Lebesgue integrable.

(Note that e.g. $\int_0^1 \ln(x) dx$ is "not on a compact interval" in this sense.)

The first situation is really not a problem, because either:

- the discontinuities of $f$ have positive measure, in which case you're dealing with a Lebesgue integral;
- or it doesn't matter, because both exist and are the same.

The second situation requires careful attention to context. For instance, one should pay careful attention to properly understand what "$\int_1^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x} dx$ exists" means.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that some courses may differ, but Riemann integration seems to be
fairly standard in your basic first textbook of integral calculus.
The standard curriculum for real analysis as I recall it was you get one year
of single-variable differential and integral calculus, 
then a year of multivariate calculus, and if you continue on from that
(which you will almost certainly not do unless you are majoring in math)
you get Lebesgue integration.
I think the reason may be it's relatively easy to explain Riemann integration;
to motivate Lebesgue integration you'd have to understand things like the reason
the set of rationals has measure zero and the set of irrationals does not.

The online course description for 
[Calculus I at the University of Houston,](http://online.math.uh.edu/Math1431/)
for example, mentions Riemann sums immediately under the heading of integration.
MIT's [open courseware Calculus lecture notes](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-01-single-variable-calculus-fall-2006/lecture-notes/lec18.pdf)
pretty clearly are using Riemann integration for the definite integral.

Comment: My experience with real analysis was a semester of single variable, a semester of "mostly multivariable" with some extra stuff added in, and then Lebesgue integration at the graduate level. All of this is after three semesters of calculus.

Comment: @Ian Sounds like a fast-track program compared to most. As I recall I may have gotten to Lebesgue integration in the first semester of college, but this was in a course that was supposed to combine second and third year analysis for math majors, and I only got into it by placing out of first year calculus completely (having taken AP calculus, which as I recall relied on Riemann integration).

Comment: I think you misunderstand. Having taken AP calculus, I came in taking calc III. Then I had some other courses (linear algebra, for example) before taking the intro to proof class in my second spring. Then I had analysis in both semesters of my junior year, which did *not* cover Lebesgue integration. (It stopped at some function space topics including the implicit function theorem.) I did Lebesgue integration in my first semester in graduate school.

Comment: @Ian I _did_ misunderstand. I thought you meant you took a graduate-level course in your second or third year of college. Such things do happen occasionally (though never to me). I suppose I should have said in my answer that some courses _will_ differ (though mainly in how long it takes to get to Lebesgue, rather than in what you start with).